# Extracting sequence of column names for Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, charsequence

I am constructing an RShiny app and am trying to generate the checkboxGroupInput options in an efficient manner.

I'd like to create a vector with every odd column name to avoid doing the below to generate the potential options for the user to select:

```
checkboxGroupInput("names","Names",c(colnames(df)[ncol(df)],colnames(df)[ncol(df)-2],colnames(df)[ncol(df)-4],etc...))
```

Is there a way to extract column names with a function like seq or letters? Ideally it would be something like, though of course the below does not work:

```
vector=c(colnames(Runs)[ncol(Runs)]:colnames(Runs)[3],-2)
```

Then I'd want to just insert that vector into the checkbox field.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with `seq` setting a negative `by` :

`colnames(df)[seq(from = ncol(df), to = 1, by = -2)]`

(It's not related to shiny though.)